# Как переместить файл в создаваемую папку незная пути Python

Tags: python, ос, zipfile

Учусь програмировать на Python, начал с книги "A byte of Python". В разделе есть задача создать програму которая перемещает файлы в зип формат. К условию сразу написано решение, которое на Windows не работает (узнал после часа попыток ), нашел решение при помощи модуля zipfile и os, вроди все ок, но после этого следует upgrate програмы который предлагает создавать деректорию в которой будет наш зип файл. Деректорию я разобрался как создавать, но как создать зип файл в создаваемой деректории?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проиинициализируем ситуацию: я захотел вам помочь и хочу проверить, как ваш код будет работать у меня. как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Как это пути не знаете? Вы же сами директорию по этому пути создаёте.

Просто перетасуйте строчки 7,9 и 10.

```
today = ...
target = today + os.sep + time.strftime(...) + '.zip'
z = ...
```

*(вот почему код в виде скриншотов не приветствуется - скопировать нельзя, а набивать мне лень)*